# Mysql Multilingual order

Tags: mysql, sorting

Is there any way I can create a custom order in mysql to compensate for dual language sorting.
Specific I want to sort a table that contains both English and Greek characters (titles).
what I am looking to do is force it to consider "a" and "α" (alpha - greek equivalent to a) as the same orderwise, same for "b" to "β" (beta in greek) and so on and so forth. Is there some way to force this type of ordering ?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: i don't think this is easily possible (?) sounds like a custom collation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html. A simpler apporach: you will need to create an extra column in which you will have your text there in english and if greek, in "greeklish" (greeklish is greek written with english characters). Then you can sort them.

Comment: Thanks Sharky, I actually read that already but it seems a bit out of my depth, will need to do some heavy duty research to get into that. Your suggestion is interesting though, as I could create an additional column and convert the greek to greeklish and use that for sorting. Thanks for the idea.